# Accessing variables inside class called within another class (Python)

Tags: python, class

I have one class named Master() with some variables initialized in **init**(); then, I call another class (Node) from the method1 of Master. Is there any way to pass all the variables of Master().**init**() in all the classes (Nodes) called within the first one?

The first solution is to pass all the variables directly in this way:

```
class Node():
    
    def __init__(self, arg1=0):
        self._a = None
        self._b = None    
        self._c = False
        self._arg1_node = arg1
   

    def method1(self, _arg1, _arg2, _arg3):
        print(_arg1, _arg2, _arg3)
        


class Master:
    
    def __init__(self, arg1=3, arg2=20, arg3=1):
        self._arg1 = arg1
        self._arg2 = arg2
        self._arg3 = arg3


    def method1(self):
        self._root = Node()
        self._root.method1(self._arg1, self._arg2, self._arg3)

Master().method1()
```

Is there any way to print directly without passing as function's arguments?

```
class Node():
    
    def __init__(self, arg1=0):
        self._a = None
        self._b = None    
        self._c = False
        self._arg1_node = arg1
   

    def method1(self):
        print(_arg1, _arg2, _arg3)
        


class Master:
    
    def __init__(self, arg1=3, arg2=20, arg3=1):
        self._arg1 = arg1
        self._arg2 = arg2
        self._arg3 = arg3


    def method1(self):
        self._root = Node()
        self._root.method1()
```

Comment: No. `method1` of `Node` declares 3 positional arguments so you must pass them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make three variables at the constructor, but therefore you have to give it to the function. I do not quite understand, why you do not want to pass the variables as function parameters, because if you want to use variables, which are locally stored inside of a class, in another object of another class, then you have to pass these, since they are not global variables. I think your first solution is good, because that's how you do it.